# Reset password lime survey

Tags: php, mysql, limesurvey

i have a problem with lime survey. i forgot admin password. and  I tried to update via mysql with md5 encryption. but not successfully login.

```
update lime_users set password=md5('password');
```

or

```
update lime_users set password=sha('password');
```

i want to ask, how to reset password in limesurvey.

Comment: **md5() is not an encryption algorithm, but a hash i.e. 1-way**

Comment: are you sure, that `md5` is used? maybe `sha`?

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: AFAIK, the hash used is sha256

Comment: @k102 : i has used sha but not successfully :(

Comment: You can't just randomly pick a hash method. It has to be the one LimeSurvey expects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use php cli if you have an ssh access to the server.

```
 cd ./limesurvey/application/commands/
 php starter.php resetpassword newuser newpassword
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Limesurvey 2.0 or greater using this as the hash:

```
$new_pass = hash('sha256', 'newpasswordgoeshere');
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: That's basically it - newpasswordgoeshere = the password you want, the value of $new_pass will be what should be stored in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

3 way and all are in manual : https://manual.limesurvey.org/General_FAQ#I_forgot_my_admin_password._How_do_I_reset_it.3F

1. With PHP Cli `php application/commands/console.php resetpassword NEW_ADMIN_NAME NEW_ADMIN_PASS`
2. With DB access `UPDATE lime_users SET password = 0x35653838343839386461323830343731353164306535366638646336323932373733363033643064366161626264643632613131656637323164313534326438 WHERE uid =1;` (here : password)
3. With only ftp access : https://gitlab.com/SondagesPro/coreAndTools/ResetPasswordController/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

In Lime Survey 3.3.1 running the following will generate a hash for a new password on the command line:

```
php -r "echo password_hash('new password goes here', PASSWORD_DEFAULT); echo \"\n\";"
```

This will print out the hashed password, which you need to copy.

Then you can update the specific user's password in whatever SQL CLI you use:

```
UPDATE users set password = 'paste the password hash here' 
WHERE uid=[the uid for the user you're interested in];
```

Comment: What do you mean, "old hash"? Is that relevant to my version of lime survey? Also, It's funny that your manual didn't come up when I was searching.

Comment: old hash : sha256, new hash (LimeSurvey 3.X) password_hash. But LimeSurvey 3 accept old hash (sha256) in password column. And use new one after first connexion.

Comment: @Denis, Why would you deliberately use an outdated hash technique? That's madness.

Comment: Because 1. It work, 2. It was resetted at 1st logon, 3. More easy to update with sha256 in DB. 4. I give 3 method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378688/2239406 5. I use API method in controller : https://gitlab.com/SondagesPro/coreAndTools/ResetPasswordController/blob/master/ResetPasswordController.php#L39

Comment: The usage of `password_hash()` is correct, but you must update the `users` table, not `lime_users`.

Answer (score -1):

I have access to the DB with PhpMyAdmin on a Linux server with MySQL. Found this syntax that worked for a 3.17.x version

```
UPDATE `yourprefix_users`
SET yourprefix_users.password = sha2('YourNewPassword',256) WHERE uid = 1
```

Change uid with the one you want to reset in case is not about the admin that has the uid=1.